# SELECT EXPAND vs TRAVERSE

Tags: sql, orientdb

I've been playing around with OrientDB's default database about Grateful Dead.

I am struggling to get equal results from two queries which should deliver the same result. But they do not.

query 1:

```
select from ( traverse in(sung_by) from #9:8 while $depth<=1 ) where type='song' order by @rid
```

this means: start from the given node, go through all 'sung_by' incoming edges not farther than 1 node away, throw away starting vertex.

query 2:

```
select expand( in(sung_by) ) from #9:8 order by @rid
```

this means: start from the same given vertex, expand accordingly to all incoming 'sung_by' edges.

I suppose these queries have to return the same result... but i get a different value already at the 4th record. Additionally, if one tries to calculate the total number of records returned, then in the former case that would be 148, and in the latter - 150.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

i found the problem, and it is weird. it's in the quotation marks of 'sung_by'. if it's present, queries

```
select * from ( traverse in('sung_by') from #9:8 ) where type='song'
```

and

```
select expand( in('sung_by') ) from #9:8
```

deliver exactly the same result.

I do not understand why it ran without quotation marks in the first place, and secondly I do not understand which records were selected.

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd query try this:

`select from (select expand( in(sung_by) ) from #9:8) order by @rid`

This means start from `#9:8` and expand to all incoming `sung_by` edges. Now keep this result and show it to me ordered by `@rid`.

The problem with your query must be at the `order by` part.  This becomes clear if you put `limit -1` at the end of your query (that is, bring all results without pagination). Then the results should be the same for both your queries. It's like it's not so clear when `order by` should be applied and to what result set, so we become more explicit with inner query.

Answer (score 0):

can you try your 2nd query as below :

```
select expand(set(in(sung_by))) from #9:8 order by @rid
```